# Why can't popmin in binomial heap just take the main root value?

Tags: data-structures, heaps

Why is there a need to scan each root node of the binomial trees in a binomial heap to find the minimum?

For example, why can't the true **root** of the binomial heap, the one that leads to the root nodes of the binomial trees, be the minimum? If it is not the minimum, then what value should it be?

[image]

Comment: Just because the minimum *could* be at a particular root doesn't mean it is *guaranteed* to be at that place.

Comment: Does that mean for the root that connects to all the roots of the binomial trees, it doesn't actually have a value? if there is a value, (e.g. 13 nodes in such a heap, 1 root, +8 from 1 binomial tree and +4 from another binomial tree). How do you get the value of that 1 root? and how is it chosen?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Perhaps it would help if you edited the question to provide more context, show an example, etc.  Please define all terms.  I don't know what you mean by a "true root".  I don't know what you mean by "doesn't actually have a value".  Perhaps it would help if you found a textbook that describes binomial heaps and read that.  Don't just rely on Wikipedia as your only source; it's often not an ideal source for self-learning.